# Constrast stretching Sentinel-2 L1C

Tags: qgis, sentinel-2, sentinel-hub

I've just read the new [post at Medium](https://medium.com/sentinel-hub/color-correction-with-javascript-d721e12a919) about Sentinel-2 color correction with Sentinel Playground. It says that

> The default gain factor is set to 2.5, which corresponds to white-point reflectance of 40% (a pixel with 40% or more reflectance in all three bands will appear white in the resulting image).

I get very similar visual result by stretching contrast in QGIS [0, 4095] --> [0, 255] for each band. I've chosen these ranges based on histogram and [radiometric resolution of 12 bits](https://earth.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/resolutions/radiometric). Please, help me understand what operations are performed with the image when setting gain factor at Sentinel Playground?

[image: gain 2.5 image from sentinel playground]

[image: stretched [0,4095] in QGIS]

[image: histogram of the image in QGIS]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check Sentinel-2 technical specifications, etc. S2 MPC Data Quality Report, you will find:

*The L1C product quantization value has been set to 10 000: a Digital Number (DN) of 10 000 corresponds to a reflectance of 1, while a Digital Number of 1 represents a minimal value of the reflectance (0.001). The Digital Number 0 is a fill value (No Data), used for L1C pixels outside of the instrument observation swath.*

Without any "gain factor" this would mean that reflectance 0 (DN=0) would be black and reflectance 1 (DN=10.000) would be white. Gain factor of 2.5 stretches the reflectance range so that 0 (DN=0) -> 0 , 0.2 (DN=2.000) -> 0.5, 0.4 (DN=4.000) -> 1.0, eveything above 0.4 is 1.0 as well.

So... long story short, your stretching contrast [0,4095] is almost the same as Sentinel Hub's [0,4000].